# How to declare an enum variable null?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, enums

I'm new to Objective C. Here's my code

```
enum effectName {
    RESET, Flea,Tint,Grayscale,Pixelate,Blur,Mirror,changeBrightness,changeContrast,Invert
};
enum effectName EffectToApply;        
enum effectName prevEffect;
```

and in the implementation file, I've to declare EffectToApply and prevEffect as null. I tried doing it like this

```
-(void) Effect    
{        
     EffectToApply= NULL;        
     prevEffect=nil;
}
```

but it gives a warning Incompatible pointer to integer conversion. Can someone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

An enum is effectively an integer and, like an integer, such a type cannot represent a NULL value discreet from 0 in either C or Objective-C<sup>1</sup>

The simplest way to deal with this is to have a "NONE" enum option, generally with the value 0.

```
enum effectName {
    NoEffect, ResetEffect, ..
};

enum effectName EffectToApply; // default value => 0 / NoEffect
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See [Can a conforming C implementation #define NULL to be something wacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599207/can-a-conforming-c-implementation-define-null-to-be-something-wacky) for a lot of C-lawyer speak wrt how NULL is defined; some libraries [define NULL as 0 or 0L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288482/is-null-in-c-required-defined-to-be-zero), which while permissible would (unfortunately) not have emitted the observed warnings.