# Is there a difference between initialiazing variables and pointers with NULL or 0?

Tags: c, variables, pointers, initialization, null-pointer

Which of the following methods is a more correct way to initialize a variable?

```
int x = 0;
int x = NULL;
```

What about the pointers? I have been told discordant things about `NULL`, like : "`NULL` is best for initializing pointers" or "Don't use `NULL` but 0 to initialize a variable" and so on... Now, I  read on the internet that `NULL` is equal to 0 and I tested that myself. So what's the point? Why are some people saying that using NULL isn't a good choice? Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: `NULL` is not equal to `0`.

Comment: This question is related to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288482/is-null-in-c-required-defined-to-be-zero

Comment: @iharob You say that `if ( 0 == NULL )` is not true?

Comment: @iharob that's strange, I initialized an integer variable to NULL and when I printed the value of the variable it was 0.

Comment: That's not what I said, it's not necessarily `0`.

Comment: The `NULL` macro will always be zero-valued, although it may be a naked `0`, or `(void *) 0`, or some other integer expression that evaluates to `0`.

Comment: @iharob how can this be possible? I'm sorry if I'm missing something, I'm new to C and programming in general

Comment: @JohnBode:  Not true.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34754532/198536) below.

Comment: @i486: `NULL` is a macro. And for many C implementations, it is `#define NULL ((void *)0)`. `0` is an integer. Thus the pointer `(void *)0` is converted to an `int` before the compare. That is already implementation defined and will fail (i.e. undefined behaviour) on typical 64 bit and other systems where `int` has less bits than a pointer.

Comment: @wallyk: Yes true - [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.3.2.3/3 and footnote 66.  A null pointer *constant* (which `NULL` is defined to be) is always zero-valued.  After translation, the corresponding null pointer *value* may or may not be zero-valued.

Comment: @Olaf If you compare 32-bit `0` and 64-bit `0` the comparison will be positive, I think. Is it true?

Comment: @i486: `(void *)0` The standard is a bit [ambiguous](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) here. It allows `0` alone as _null pointer constant_ (NPC) and state that "If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer ...". Problem is it also allows `(void *)0` as NPC, which also is also a _null pointer_ due to the "cast to pointer" (`void *` is not excluded here). I prefer to take the _null pointer_ view, so that construct would already be allowed not to be all-zero. But that might be disputable.

Comment: @i486: Anyway, not providing a specific token for a _null pointer constant_ like Pascal, Modula (`NIL`) was one of the worst decissions in early C. C++ finally corrected this with `nullptr` - too bad the C commitee was not that brave.

Comment: NIL? I tried to print the value of a pointer initialized with NULL and it was (nil)

Comment: @ClaudioCortese: From the C standard (C11 n1570): "The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, **in an implementation-defined manner**." (emphasise mine). FYI: `NIL` means "Not In List". For list-based languages like LISP ("ListProcessing"), the name instantly becomes clear. Note that the libraries might not only be used by the C or the C++ language, but also e.g. by Pascal programs. Some libraries might just print the value, e.g. `0x0`, others e.g. `(null)`. AFAIK none prints uppercase `NULL` - likely for good reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` is a pointer constant.  You use this to initialize a pointer to a value that says it doesn't point to anything.

On most C implementations, it is defined as:

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

But there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: Maybe that's why a lot of people told me that's not a good idea to use NULL? This could explain the mistery for me

Comment: @ClaudioCortese Exactly.  In practice, they're usually the same, but if you depend on this behavior and then move your code to a platform where there's not, you'll have all kinds of problems.

Comment: Mhh, ok, so it's more a thing related to the portability of the code that something else, right?

Comment: @ClaudioCortese Right.  Always make your code portable, unless you have very specific reasons not to.

Comment: So the same apply to pointers, if want to declare and initialize a pointer i would do *pointer = 0 and not *pointer = NULL for portability reason, right?

Comment: @ClaudioCortese No, you *always* initialize a pointer with NULL, i.e. `int *pointer = NULL`.

Comment: OK, why? Is there a reason? I tried to print the address of a pointer, prior initializing it with NULL and then with 0, and the results were the same

Comment: As I mentioned before, NULL is *usually* 0, but not always.  So always use NULL for pointers.

Answer (score 4):

> Which of the following methods is a more correct way to initialize a variable?

```
// int x = NULL;  `NULL` implies pointer
int x = 0;        // 0 implies integer value and x is an integer.
```

> What about the pointers?

```
void *p = NULL;  // `NULL` implies pointer and p is a pointer.
//void *p = 0;   // 0 implies integer value
```

> that NULL is equal to 0

It is equal in value, though maybe not in bit pattern.  See below `+0.0, -0.0` example.

---

If `NULL` was equal to 0, always, then there would not be a need for it in C.

`NULL` is *a* null pointer consonant - it often, but does not always have a bit pattern of zeros.  A pointer with a `NULL` value will always compare equally to `0`: same value, different bit patterns.

Remember that `==` compares values, not bit patterns.

```
void *a = NULL;
if (a == NULL) Always_True();
if (a == 0) Always_True();
```

---

Example that may help.  `+0.0` and `-0.0` have the same value, same type, but different bit patterns.  Similar thing may happen with pointers.

```
int main(void) {
  double pz = +0.0;
  double nz = -0.0;
  printf("=:%d  bits:%d\n", pz == nz, memcmp(&pz, &nz, sizeof pz) == 0);  // =:1  bits:0
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is a null-pointer constant. You should use that to initialize pointer types.

From `C11`, chapter §7.19, `stddef.h`

> `NULL`
>   which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant.

and for *null-pointer constant* in C, chapter §6.3.2.3

> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type
>   `void *`, is called a null pointer constant.[...]

So, the type is that of a pointer.

For other non-pointer variables, you should be using 0.

Comment: Is there a real reason behind that or it's just  a "personal preference"?

Comment: @ClaudioCortese Which one is personal preference? The type matters. Maybe most of the cases, the implementation is _equivalent_, but it's just not the _same_. Hope it's clear. :)

Comment: I mean, if NULL == 0, why is ok to initialize pointers with NULL and why it's not ok initializing variable with NULL?

Comment: @ClaudioCortese it is _most likely_ that `NULL` == `0`, but that's not guranteed. Please notice the _"implementation-defined"_ part in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `NULL` for initializing non-pointer types, as it *may* expand to something like `(void *) 0` depending on the implementation.  Use plain `0` (or a macro or `const`-qualified variable that evaluates to plain `0`) for integral types.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use `NULL` when you're initializing (or comparing) a pointer; it's good style.

Definitely don't use NULL when you're working with integers; it's poor style (and it might very well not work.)

Don't listen to anyone suggesting that you shouldn't use `NULL` with pointers; they're probably confused.

See the C FAQ list at http://c-faq.com/null/index.html for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically `NULL` can be pointer to address different from `0`. But in practice such definition will crash large percent of software. And it is 0 (or `(void *)0`) in 99.99% of cases.

Answer (score -1):

There are/were some architectures deployed for which NULL is **not** zero:  Prime 50, Honeywell-Bull, CDC Cyber 180 series and others.   In these cases, NULL is most definitely not interchangeable with zero.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597232/198536) to another question for details of the machines affected.

Comment: Are we talking about the null pointer *constant* or the null pointer *value*?  As far as C is concerned, the null pointer constant is *always* zero-valued.

Comment: @JohnBode: Yes, it is always a good idea to differentiate between `NULL` (macro), a _null pointer_ and a _null pointer constant_.

Comment: To the point: wallyk's answer is misleading; `NULL` would typically be defined as some version of 0 *even* *on* those baroque old machines where null pointers weren't 0.  See the C FAQ list, question 5.5.